# Writing output to a new file in it's own direction with python

Tags: python, printing, output

I'm struggling with writing the output of the loop to new file. I want to name the new file the name of the variable + .txt. But I'm getting errors on the print part of the code.

```
import csv
import requests

with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file) # drop header
    varlist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]

for var in varlist:
    payload = {'api_key': 'API_key', 'query':str(var), 'results':'10', 'country':'gb', 'page':'0'}
    resp = requests.get('https://api.example.com/google', params=payload)
    print(resp.text, file=(str(var) + '.txt'))
```

How to handle this correctly?

Comment: so are you trying to write the output of `resp.text` to a file named `var.txt`  where `var` is replaced by whatever the value of `var` is ?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: the `file` key should be a _stream_ object, `print(resp.text, file=open((str(var) + '.txt')), mode='w')`

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2132.txt'` As I requested it need to be written to a new file

Comment: @cards with existing file I get: `TypeError: 'mode' is an invalid keyword argument for print()`

Comment: my bad, it is diffcult to write in comments! `mode` should be a parameter of `open` and not of `print`. I mix-up with the brackets. the file key should be a stream object, `print(resp.text, file=open((str(var) + '.txt'), mode='w'))`

Comment: Yes I already solved it myself. Thanks for sending me into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the problem with putting file key in a better stream object and use 'w'

```
for var in varlist:
    payload = {'api_key': 'API_key', 'query':str(var), 'results':'10', 'country':'gb', 'page':'0'}
    resp = requests.get('https://api.example.com/google', params=payload)
    print(resp.text, file=open((str(var) + '.txt'), mode='w'))
```